# How do I configure a Json provider for a JAX-RS test client using Spring?

Tags: spring, junit, client-side, jax-rs

I have set up a JAX-RS service using Apache CXF, which I would like to test using Apache CXF JAX-RS' Client API. The server has been configured to use Jackson as the json provider. Now I would like to do the same for the client: that is, letting Jacson handle the conversion to/from json.

Unfortunately I am unsure of how to "spring enable" the tests, having only superficial knowledge of Spring. I got away with programmatically setting up a provider in the test, but would like to know how to do it through Spring. So instead of

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setup() {
    ProviderFactory.getSharedInstance().registerUserProvider(new JacksonJsonProvider());
}
```

I would want to just set it in springConfiguration.xml (or something like that :). When setting up the serverside, springConfiguration.xml looked like this.

```
<bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider"/>

<jaxrs:server id="restContainer" address="/">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="echoService"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>

    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean="jsonProvider" />
    </jaxrs:providers>

    <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
        <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
    </jaxrs:extensionMappings>
</jaxrs:server>
```

I tried to just add

```
<jaxrs:client id="restClient" >
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean="jsonProvider" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:client>
```

to springConfiguration.xml, but that did not do anything. No surprise, as I have not set up my JUnit tests to use Spring ...  Could anyone tell me how to do this, or point me to any good resources with which I could assemble the necessary info?

Answer (score 1):

The following annotations will load your application context prior to tests being run.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"applicationContext.xml"}) 
public class JaxRsTest {

  @Autowired
  MyBean myBean

  public void testMyBean() {
    //add some real tests here...
    assertNotNull(myBean)
  }

}
```

Comment: ooh, will try that as soon as I get back to work. will mark your answer as accepted as soon as I see that it works :)

Comment: That might load the context, but my JAX-RS configuration does not seem to be right. Any clues? I just get a lot of errors saying there is no message body writer for the various classes in use. In addition to using the above minimal jaxrs:client configuration, I have also tried:
    <jaxrs:client id="restClient" serviceClass="com.testing.ParamsWrapperService"
                  address="http://localhost:8080/rest/bigparam">
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean="jsonProvider"/>
        </jaxrs:providers>
    </jaxrs:client>

Comment: I haven't used Apache CXF JAX-RS previously; most of my testing is done with Spring's RestTemplate. Can you post the stack trace?